# How to speed Rails 5 dev environment for frontend work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Do you know any way of improving the development environment for frontend work for a Rails 5 app. We have a pretty huge one, and every page load after doing some changes to views / css it's about 10-20 seconds, which seems a lot for me.

I've searched for some solutions here, but are mostly referenced to Rails 3 and won't work in our current environment. I guess should be better ways to improve the frontend experience right now.

We are using pure rails. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do the servers logs show any error ?

Comment: No, there are no errors Maxence.

Comment: It's huge. It is instant for me. Are you coding on Windows ? Also I asked for any logged errors like missing assets ... Missing assets trigger warnings that really delay the display of the views..

Comment: We are on Mac Maxence. I will review the logs tomorrow, but I don't remember any asset error. Thanks anyway!

Comment: No apparent errors. This is our last 'rails s' output line: Completed 200 OK in 29797ms (Views: 28950.8ms | ActiveRecord: 482.9ms).

Comment: 28 seconds for a single view ? Can you post the full logs after you do a view refresh? .. You also can probably spot the bottleneck just watching the logs appear. It surely slows down at some point..

Comment: This is the homepage, and we load a lot of stuff. The bigger bottlenecks are some articles loading there 500ms each one, but the sql time is under 10ms. I can't understand what could be the cause of those extra 490ms.